# colorAccent or colorSecondary with Material Component theme

Tags: android, android-theme, material-components, material-components-android

When creating a new app using the wizard of Android Studio a theme derived from `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` is used and a `colorAccent` is set. On the other side the [official documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/color/) uses `colorSecondary` and doesn't mention `colorAccent` at all. Are both interchangeable? What to prefer?

Comment: There isn't any Theme.MaterialComponents  in my case

Comment: Maybe because I checked to use androidx in the setup wizard. In my case, it is the default theme Android Studio sets up new apps.

Comment: Ok, I checked again ... it seems to be part of com.google.android.material:material package, see https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/, and I seem to added it manually somewhen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Theme.MaterialComponents` uses the `colorSecondary` as described in the [material guidelines](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/color/) and in the [official doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).
All the components defined in the library uses this attribute.

However, in the library, there are also the [`Bridge` themes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#bridge-themes-bridge-themes) which inherit from `AppCompat` themes and you can use them, if you cannot change your theme to inherit from a Material Components theme.
These themes inherit from `AppCompat` themes defining the new Material Components theme attributes for you.

You can check the [bridge theme in the library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0-beta02/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/res/values/themes_base.xml#L28):

```
<style name="Base.V14.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light" parent="Base.V14.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">

  <!-- Colors -->
  <item name="colorAccent">?attr/colorSecondary</item>
```

Here you can find the mapping between `colorSecondary` and the `colorAccent` for these themes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I do believe `colorSecondary` is the new term for `colorAccent` and are interchangeable because if you read the [docs](https://material.io/design/color/#color-theme-creation) specifically the definition of secondary color it says

> A secondary color provides more ways to ***accent*** and distinguish your
>   product. Having a secondary color is optional, and should be applied
>   sparingly to ***accent*** select parts of your UI.

I guess just from that statement it is pretty clear that they both have the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As per the material design documentation, the primary color and the secondary color are actually the **primaryColor** and **accentColor** in Android Studio. But if more variations are required then the **secondaryColor** can be used.

So prefer accentColor tag in Android Studio to define the secondary color from material design documentation.

You can try out some material palettes like https://www.materialpalette.com to understand the behaviour.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct. As more and more I read about it, it seems that `accentColor` is for `AppCompat` themes and `secondaryColor` is for `MaterialComponents` themes, see [here for example](https://proandroiddev.com/my-experience-with-material-design-components-5fd9da343e89). But absolutely confusing.

Comment: After reviewing all the articles, it looks like the colorSecondary is the thing that should be used with Material design. I'd use accentColor if only using the AppCompat theme.